# A complex regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I had to write a regular expression to match string. I will be using .net C#.

1. Character 1 must be alphabetic [A-Z,a-z].
2. Character 2 must be a hyphen.
3. Characters 3 through 6 must be numeric [0-9], alphabetic [A-Z,a-z], or caret [^].
4. If any character 3 through 6 has [^], all subsequent characters must equal [^].

I ended up writing below expression:

```
[a-zA-Z][-]([0-9a-zA-Z\^]{4})
```

But I dont know how to take care the 4th criteria.

I am new in writing regex so whatever I have written is by going through the tutorials. It will be great help if someone can help me in completing the regex and share links or break the regex and explain it so that I can learn and write more complex regex henceforth.

Comment: Regular expression matching can occur anywhere in the string, [unless you specify anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) - in your case, as you want to match character 1, you should use `\A` at the start of your regex, to assert the position at the beginning of the string. And if I understand right, it should be exactly 6 characters in length, so you will want to use `\z` at the end of your regex.  Also .NET has a case insensitive option, which can simplify your (Latin) alphabetic character check to just [A-Z].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like it might be written simpler but here you go:

```
^[a-zA-Z]-([0-9a-zA-Z]|\^(?=($|\^))){4}$
```

I modified your regex a bit and added the last condition.

- added `^` and `$` at the beginning and end to match the whole string only
- removed `[]` where they are not necessary around `-`
- removed `()` around the last group - not necessary

The last condition is done by changing the last group to either `[0-9a-zA-Z]` (this is easy) or `\^(?=($|\^))`. This is the special treatment of the caret:

- Caret has to be followed by end of string or another caret `(?=($|\^))`. This uses a look ahead positive assertion to make sure that there can be only carets between the first caret and the end.

Comment: This worked! Thank you Szymon. So basically [0-9a-zA-Z]|\^
tells that the allowed characters are numeric,alphabet or caret.
Then (?=($|\^))
tells that next character should be end of line or a caret.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @thinkmmk Almost, the order is different. It's [0-9a-zA-Z] or \^(?=($|\^)) which means it's alphnumeric or caret followed by another caret or end of line.

Answer (score -1):

Go to RegEx101: https://regex101.com/r/lC1pD7/1

I inserted your partial regex there.
It has a quick reference that will make it a snap to complete, test and understand.

[I'm not affiliated with them in any way]